# LUIS: Speech sdk - Github Sample does not returning the intent

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I am trying to run the sample [tutorial-speech-intent-recognition](https://github.com/Microsoft/LUIS-Samples/tree/master/documentation-samples/tutorial-speech-intent-recognition) with the latest SDK
[image]

I am able to invoke the sdk and get the speech recognized, however its not returning the correct intent. instead it always gets into `result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech`

[image]

However when I try the same text in the test panel, its working.

[image]

can someone please help me understand what may be going wrong here.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: Have you saved, trained and published the changes to your luis entities? I usually have this issue when I forgot to click on the publish button

Comment: @Gonzix yes, I have also published the model. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I was out for some days. Have you figure it out? If not, what happens if you check the getIntentId method of your result? have you tried using postman to see the raw answer?

Comment: 2 things that could help for debugging: add the capture of your `Inspect` panel in LUIS with "compare with published" clicked (to ensure that published model is correctly answering). You can also give a try to your model by text and check if the result is right