# tutorial-speech-intent-recognition not working?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I've been using this example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-language-understanding/tree/master/documentation-samples/tutorial-speech-intent-recognition/csharp

Configured it correctly, i've already created luis app, added some intents and examples, trained and published. And i've commented out the model part cos i already have luis app made.

When i run the app recognition seems fine, but i didn't get the intent (result.IntentId is blank), thought in luis everything is fine. Also everythings working if im taking recognized text and quiring luis using rest. 
What's wrong?
I've found issue very similar to that on SO, but there's no answer and i can't comment there: [LUIS: Speech sdk - Github Sample does not returning the intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53303857/luis-speech-sdk-github-sample-does-not-returning-the-intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after investigating a bit more i found out that `recognizer.AddIntent(model,...` lines was not about CREATING new intents in model but rather mapping intents from luis app to our local app to have some ids here. On github i've been told that there's `recognizer.AddAllIntents(model);` line for working with all intents, with this line everything's working.